# How to add gravity to pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I've tried to add gravity using the quadratic formula but didn't seem to work and I tried to turn it into a function and that still didn't seem to work. I tried using a class but I don't quite understand how they work so can someone help me add gravity to my platformer. I've tried many videos but didn't seem to help so any help would be much appreciated

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import mixer
from typing import Tuple
import pickle
from os import path
import time
import sys
import os
pygame.init()



white = 255,255,255
black = 0,0,0
green = 0, 255, 0
blue = 0,0,255
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 50, 70)
screen_width = 650
screen_height = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width,screen_height])
screen.fill((white))
pygame.display.set_caption("Darsh's Game")
pygame.display.update()
pygame.draw.rect(screen,white,(200,150,100,50))
running = 1
speed = 1
x = 25
y = 669
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
left = False
right = True


def draw_text(text, font, text_col, x, y):
    img = font.render(text, True, text_col)
    screen.blit(img, (x, y))

def draw_rect():
    rect1 = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 25, 800)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, rect1)
    rect2 = pygame.Rect(625, 0, 25, 800)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, rect2)
    rect3 = pygame.Rect(0, 775, 650, 25)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, rect3)
    pygame.display.flip()

def direction(left, right):
    if left == True:
        screen.blit(mainleft_img, (x, y))
    elif right == True:
        screen.blit(mainright_img, (x, y))
    draw_rect()
    draw_text("George is dumb", font, green, 100, 400)
    pygame.display.update()



mainright_img = pygame.image.load('newgameimg/mainright.png')
mainleft_img = pygame.image.load('newgameimg/mainleft.png')
screen.blit(mainright_img, (300, 400))




run = True
while run:
    draw_text("George is dumb", font, green, 100, 400)
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > speed - 16:
        x -= speed
        left = True
        right = False
        draw_text("George is dumb", font, green, 100, 400)
        pygame.display.update()
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < screen_width - speed - 89:
        x += speed
        left = False
        right = True
        draw_text("George is dumb", font, green, 100, 400)
        pygame.display.update()
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        pygame.quit()

    if not (isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:  # jumping code
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            time.sleep(0.02)
            y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False  # jumping code

    screen.fill(white)
    direction(left, right)
    draw_text("George is dumb", font, green, 100, 400)
    draw_rect()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the quadratic formula to get a simple gravity going; a simple gravity variable increasing every frame should do the trick.

```py
...
gravity = 0

while run:
  ...
  ...
  if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    gravity += 1
    y -= gravity
  ...
```

Note that I don't speak your language; I mainly code in JavaScript, but I did try python once and I got the syntax down pretty quick. Hopefully this suits your needs, with a bit of tweaking of course.

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable `fall = 0`. Increment the variable if the player does not jump (`fall += 0.2`). Change the `y` coordinate of the player through the variable `fall` in each frame. Get the bounding rectangle of the player with [`pygame.Surface.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html). If the bottom of the rectangle reaches the floor then stop falling, and restricting the bottom of the rectangle on the floor. Set `fall = 0` if the player starts to jump:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    if not (isJump):
        fall += 0.2
        y += fall
        player_rect = mainleft_img.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
        if player_rect.bottom > 775:
            player_rect.bottom = 775
            y = player_rect.top
            fall = 0
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:  # jumping code
            isJump = True
            fall = 0
    else:
        # [...]
```

---

Multiple calls to `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` cause flickering. Remove all calls to `pygame.display.update()` from your code, but call it once at the end of the application loop.
In addition, draw each object only once.

---

Do not `delay`, `wait` or `sleep`. Use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

That means that the loop:

> ```py
> clock = pygame.time.Clock()
> run = True
> while run:
>    clock.tick(60)
> ```

runs 60 times per second.

See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame. It will compute how many milliseconds have passed since the previous call.

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

white = 255,255,255
black = 0,0,0
green = 0, 255, 0
blue = 0,0,255

screen_width = 650
screen_height = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width,screen_height])
pygame.display.set_caption("Darsh's Game")
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 50, 70)

running = 6
speed = 2
fall = 0
x = 25
y = 669
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
left = False
right = True

def draw_text(text, font, text_col, x, y):
    img = font.render(text, True, text_col)
    screen.blit(img, (x, y))

def draw_rect():
    rect1 = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 25, 800)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, rect1)
    rect2 = pygame.Rect(625, 0, 25, 800)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, rect2)
    rect3 = pygame.Rect(0, 775, 650, 25)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, rect3)

def direction(left, right):
    if left == True:
        screen.blit(mainleft_img, (x, y))
    elif right == True:
        screen.blit(mainright_img, (x, y))
    draw_text("George is dumb", font, green, 100, 400)

mainright_img = pygame.image.load('newgameimg/mainright.png')
mainleft_img = pygame.image.load('newgameimg/mainleft.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > speed - 16:
        x -= speed
        left = True
        right = False
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < screen_width - speed - 89:
        x += speed
        left = False
        right = True
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        pygame.quit()

    if not (isJump):
        fall += 0.2
        y += fall
        player_rect = mainleft_img.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
        if player_rect.bottom > 775:
            player_rect.bottom = 775
            y = player_rect.top
            fall = 0
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:  # jumping code
            isJump = True
            fall = 0
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False  # jumping code

    screen.fill(white)
    draw_rect()
    direction(left, right)    
    pygame.display.update()
```